# Implement Forget password in asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could anyone show me some code about the forget password sample? I have no idea about that. For my login and remember me, I used Membership provider of asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regardless to membership provider, here is a small example of change password:

- Create action that requests user's email
- Generate new password but not change it in database
- Generate encrypted token that contains about user id and generated password
- Create action that accepts token, decrypt it and reset password for user
- Make url to action that accepts token as parameter, resets password and redirects to login page
- Generate email message with url to action that resets password

Answer (score 4):

Forgotten Password functionality is usually a business decision, there are multiple ways to implement it.

For example, the ASP.NET Membership Provider offers a secret question / answer policy, and you can reset the password if it validates; or you could also just have the system reset the password itself, and email the password to the user anyway.

[This](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/Password-Recovery-in-an-ASP.NET-MVC-Project) is a good post that seems to cover most of the issues for the former approach, and is implemented in ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks,

Matt